# how to transfer file using bash script serieswise?

Tags: bash, shell, system-administration

### There are two types file.

1. Book1_20190715_1A.gz,
2. Book1_20190715A.gz,
3. Book2_20190716_1A.gz,
4. Book2_20190716A.gz

   Here, 2019 is year 07 is month & 15 is date also 16.
   Also here is two type file _1A & A.

   **Need to Transfer Date-wise in Folder.
   Also Need to transfer different folder for different type file like _1A & A**

If I **grep** like ***_1A** then it transfer _1A folder But if ***A** then it transfer A also _1A.

```
What I do now. Please Help me.
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: #1 #2 #3 #4 seem to be file names; if so, why are you using `grep`? Are these file names stored inside a text  file?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. *”There are 2 types of file, 1 through 4”* ? Please show what you start with and also what you hope to end up with. Thank you.

Comment: Missing your attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: @Fravadona No, This is files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes here is 2 types file. one is _1A & another is A. But I write here 4 files to show you different date.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but this is what I think you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch Book1_20190715_1A.gz
touch Book1_20190715A.gz
touch Book2_20190716_1A.gz
touch Book2_20190716A.gz

find . -type f -name "Book*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    # Remove "Book1_"
    tempdirname=${file#*_}
    # Remove ".gz"
    dirname=${tempdirname%\.*}
    echo "$dirname"
    if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
    then
        mkdir "$dirname"
    fi
    /bin/mv "$file" "$dirname"
done
```

- the `find` lists all files named `Book*` and sends that list to a `while` loop.
- from the filename, extract the directory name using variable expansion.  First remove "Book1_", then remove ".gz".  This leaves you with the date, and the "_1A" portion, if it is there.
- then create the directory if it does not already exist.
- move the file to the directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to move separate directory for 'A' & '_1A' file.

Comment: Did you try the script?  It does create separate directories for A and _1A.

Comment: Yes I try. But it create separate directory for separate file.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the `touch` of files.  This is how I tested.  You question says `Need to transfer different folder for different type file like _1A & A`.  So my script creates one directory per date (`0715` and `0716`), and one directory for `A` files, and another for `_1A` files.  If you want something else, say so, or edit the script according to your real needs.